# In a Windows.Forms application, Properties.Resources always return neutral culture values

Tags: .net, resources

I have a Windows.Forms application and I change the resources at runtime with this code:

`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("it-IT");`

What happens is that new forms appear correctly with the new culture, while Properties.Resources.* strings always appear with the neutral culture (even if Properties.Resources.Culture appears correctly set to "it-IT").

How can I make my program reload Properties.Resources.* strings after chaning the culture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should happen automatically. Make sure that you have created the localized resources correctly:

1. Neutral culture goes into `<filename>.resx`
2. Italian culture goes into `<filename>.it-IT.rex` (or `<filename>.it.resx`)

Comment: I have a file called Resources.it.resx in the main folder of the application and it's added to the project as "Embedded resource". Should it go somewhere else?

Comment: Is it located in the same place as Resources.resx?

Comment: Thank you, it was in the wrong place: it should have been in the Properties subdir instead of in the main dir.